# Freemarker - loop variables not surviving nested macro call

Tags: freemarker

I have the following freemarker template:

```
[#local snippet ][#noparse]
        [#assign out ]value: ${v}
        [/#assign]
    [/#noparse]
[/#local]
[#assign hook = snippet?interpret ]
...
[#macro trigger ]
    [@hook /]
[/#macro]
...
[#list values as v ]
    [@trigger ]
[/#list]
${out}
```

What it essentially does is defining a hooks to execute at a certain later moment and a macro to trigger it's execution.

When I try to render this template, i get the following error:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> v  [in template "xxx.ftl->anonymous_interpreted" at line 1, column 17]
```

It might be interesting to note that the following:

```
[#list values as v ]
    [@hook ]
[/#list]
```

is just working, i.e. rendering the template as I would expect, printing `value: xxx` for each value in the list.

- Does anybody know what is going wrong here?
- Is there any way to make this work as expected?

### EDIT

I just discovered that the error doesn't occur if instead of an interpreted snippet I pass a regular macro:

```
[#assign hook = myMacro ]
...
```

but not if the macro is defined in another namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop variable (`v`) is basically a local variable of the `#list` block. So, with Java-ish pseudo-code what you try to do is like:

```
void main() {
   for (int v : values) {
      trigger();
   }
}

void trigger() {
   print(v);  // Error, v is not visible here!
}
```

As of calling a directive defined with `?interpret`, that's special, as it tries to behave as if you have copy-pasted the code snippet at the place of invocation. That is, the directive that you call with `@hook` doesn't create its own local context. So that's why it sees `v` if you call it *directly* from the loop. But if you call it form `trigger`, then it will live in the local context of the `trigger` macro, which do have its own local context.

As of making it work... one possibility is assigning `v` to a namespace-scope variable via `<#assign value = v>`, and then refer to `value` in the interpreted fragment. Another solution is of course getting rid of the `trigger` indirection, if you can. Yet another solution is to define `trigger` with `?interpret` instead of with `#macro`, because then `trigger` will see `v`, and so `hook` will too.

Comment: Mumble... this makes things a bit more clear, but what about the edit, then?

Comment: I guess don't understand that edit, as I can't see `v` from `myMacro` either. Can you give a more complete example?

Comment: Yes never mind, I've been mistaken. I tried again making up a better example and everything went as you predicted. I'm accepting this answer ;-)